# How to receive "callbackContext.sendPluginResult" result?

Tags: android, cordova-plugins

Whenever I send

```
callbackContext.sendPluginResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, 0));
```

on my onClick function. I receive this in my logcat

```
W/CordovaPlugin: Attempted to send a second callback for ID: DemoPlugin1910499679
                                                                    Result was: 0
```

I can receive response from

```
callbackContext.success();
```

in my JS successCallback function. But I can't receive callback from `.sendPluginResult()`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `callbackContext.sendPluginResult()` can't work together with `callbackContext.success()`.

I remove `callbackContext.success()` and left only `callbackContext.sendPluginResult()`. Only then I was able to get the result at my JS callback function.